# Orange outlines in 2d animation won't go away and let me animate a new key

Tags: animation

I can't draw and make a new keyframe on an object (I think that's the term for it) called "Boards-BG". I tried deselecting it, making sure I was in draw mode from what I heard in other threads, but either I'm doing it wrong, or it's another problem

I'm a complete noob, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but any solutions is very appreciated!

[image: Orange outlines]

Comment: from your screenshot you have 2 objects selects. go back to object mode and make sure you only have 1 selected before going back to draw mode.

Comment: Ooh, thank you for the answer! And while it did work, it always appears again shortly after and then I have to change modes over and over again. Is that a normal thing that I should be accustomed to? It happens when I switch through objects to sketch out the BGs and characters separately ^^;

Comment: yeah, going back to object mode is the only way to change the selected object (selecting in the outliner whilst in draw mode works as a "multiple object select", which is a pain). Using the mode pie menu (ctrl+tab) makes it slightly faster, but sometimes you might be better off working in the layers of just one object, and split that into different objects later, when you want parallax effects.

Comment: UPDATE! a new patch sorted this out! whilst in draw mode you can just hover over the gp-object you want and press the tilde key to switch to it. It's probably just in the experimental builds for now, but it's super super useful!

Comment: Ooh, thanks for the update!... Sorry for the late reply, but I decided to work within 1 object like you said and it's been easy sailing so far for the sketch! ...